# Login control for browser tabs in java/javascript

Tags: java, javascript, session, authentication, richfaces

I've a web application in java/jsf with richfaces.
And i've to make a client control to my login, for block multiple tabs login.

Example: When logged in a tab, i cannot login in the same application in another tab in the same browser.

Someone knows some framework or something thats make it ?

I tried to make by myself, but this control is a lot complicated because my JSessionID do not change for new tabs, all tabs in a browser session contains the same JSessionID.
The javascript instance is no equal to all tabs, and i can save cookies to control it. But, my control is to weak, cleaning the cookies break all my code security.

Sorry for my poor english... :)

Comment: You can't differentiate between different tabs/windows using server-side code. It'd have to be client-side, and therefore subject to tampering.

Comment: You are trying to stop a behavior that is by design - I highly doubt you will find a suitable solution.  Your best bet is to design the application to allow multiple tabs open in the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are "global" to a single browser instance.  If they weren't, then sites could not (for example) open up separate pop-up browser windows (and have things work properly).

Comment: i save a cookie with name "logged", and with value "true". when i loggin with another tab (in same browser), i verified the cookie, and if true i blocked the login. But, this solution is very weak.

Comment: I agree.  Why not simply let the browser work the way it's supposed to?

Comment: What is "reason" for trying to block the user from using more than 1 tab at once?  Does the framework you are using not support it? or is there a "business requirement" that only 1 tab be used?

Comment: i work with @RaduqSantos in this project, is a "business requeriment" from our boss. I already tryed to put in his mind that sh*t wrong, but he simpley don't accept it. be an employee is crap sometimes..

Comment: The thing is that if the user logs in and gets a JSESSIONID cookie, then they will be able to use another tab *without logging in* - in other words, they'll be able to get to any page a logged-in user can get to, from any tab.  You cannot prevent it because the browser will send back **all** your cookies from **any** tab.